# Returning a blank cell when there is no data

Tags: google-sheets

I want to change this function so that if AR4 is blank then the corresponding cell is also blank. Right now it is saying DNP. The function I am using is

```
=IFS(AR4>445, "P", AR4<446, "DNP")
```

Comment: Related: [Return a blank when cell reference is blank](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44796/88163) Not a duplicate yet because, IMHO, the current answers with a score > 0 are wrong or too convoluted, by the other hand the other question involves the uso of ARRAYFORMULA while this one not.

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

```
=IFS(ISBLANK(AR4),,AR4>445, "P", AR4<446, "DNP")
```

## Explanation

- ISBLANK checks is a cell is blank (completely empty)
- IFS, IF and other similar functions returns blank when the corresponding argument is blank.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!!!  So, can you tell me how to change a simple subtraction function to also return a blank cell if either of the 2 cells is blank?